# Sort table id's cut by a hyphen (PHP/MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table that I would like to display in a decreasing way. The problem is that the ID is broken by a dash ... So MySQL does not understand my request.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id ORDER BY id DESC
```

results

```
20633-18489
184945-190028
183661-188782
1575-1610
```

but I want this order

```
184945-190028
183661-188782
20633-18489
1575-1610
```

What is the solution in php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the SQL statement, we could do this:

```
 ORDER BY id + 0 DESC
```

or this:

```
 ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(id,'-',1) + 0 DESC
```

The "`+ 0`" is going to cause the string before it to be evaluated in a numeric context. That will return a number. And then the ordering will be by the numeric value.

---

As a demonstration

```
SELECT t.id
     , t.id + 0 AS id0
     , SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.id,'-',1)+0 AS id1
  FROM ( SELECT '184945-190028' AS id
         UNION ALL SELECT '183661-188782'
         UNION ALL SELECT '20633-18489'
         UNION ALL SELECT '1575-1610'
       ) t
 ORDER BY t.id + 0  DESC
```

returns

```
id                id0     id1
-------------  ------  ------
184945-190028  184945  184945
183661-188782  183661  183661
20633-18489     20633   20633
1575-1610        1575    1575
```

---

Note: this is ordering only on the part of the `id` before the dash. This doesn't specify what order id values that "match" on the leading portion will be returned in. MySQL would be free to return these two in any order.

```
456-42
456-321
```

We can add more expressions to the ORDER BY clause to make the order of these deterministic.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the `REPLACE()` FUNCTION

so your query would look like:

```
SELECT *,  REPLACE(id, '-' , '') AS sortable_id  WHERE id ORDER BY sortable_id DESC
```

Comment: This will be ordering by character (*string*) values, and won't satisfy OP specification.

Comment: @spencer7593 I do not see anything about the requirement in the original question. I am not sure if converting from string to integer before sorting is faster than sorting based on string values. Can you please elaborate what is wrong with my answer/reasoning [i would like to know to improve]

Comment: @ YouriKoeman:  look at the "i want this order" specified by OP, and look at the strings `18..`, `20...`, `15...`   if we order by strings in descending order, we're going to get `20...`, `18...`, `15...`.  The order that OP wants the values returned looks like It's by *numeric* value... compared as numeric value, 20633 is less than 183661. Compared as strings, '20xxx' is greater than '18xxx'.  (In this case, it doesn't matter if one way is faster than the other, if one of those ways isn't returning rows in the order we want.)